# how to define API KEY when make a get request with aiohttp in python?

Tags: python, httprequest, aiohttp

I want to use aiohttp in python to make a get request to an api but I dont know how to define API KEY  when create request the document of the api shows we cant pass API key with url .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this -

```py
async def request(endpoint: str, api_key: str, method: str = "GET", **kwargs) -> dict:
    url = "https://example.com/api/" + endpoint
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        async with session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as resp:
            if resp.status != 200:
                raise Exception

            return await resp.json()
```